# deepin os: deb package installation error: dpkg error processing archive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, debian, package-managers

I am trying to install apps(Deb) downloaded from chrome. When i first installed chrome using package installer it worked fine. but later i tried to install other apps it didn't work.
[image]

i even tried to install through terminal but same output again.
[image]

- after install chrome i run following for updating and installing purpose

1. sudo apt-get update &&  sudo apt-get install yarn
2. sudo apt update
3. sudo apt install python3.11
4. installed nodejs 14

before running above, package manager was working fine.
I need guidance to resolve this issue.
Thank you for your help.

I read a blog online and tried "sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock && sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock && sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock".
even after this, i am still not figured out the problem.

`ps aux | grep -i apt`
showing me
[image]

**Note: --force-overwrite didn't work.**